# JSON Array of "Objects" Parsing

Tags: objective-c, json

I have a JSON data (test data) coming back from my PHP into XCode in the form below. I am trying to figure out how to take each "object" in the array and create xcode objects from this.

```
NSArray *arrayJSON=jsonData[@"array"];
```

results in this below:

```
(
        {
        "name" = 31440name;
        "i_1" = 31440;
        "i_2" = 31441;
        "i_3" = 31442;
        "i_4" = 31443;
        "i_5" = 31444;
        "image" = "<null>";
    },
        {
        "name" = 96703name;
        "i_1" = 96703;
        "i_2" = 96704;
        "i_3" = 96705;
        "i_4" = 96706;
        "i_5" = 96707;
        "image" = "<null>";
    },
        {
        "name" = 367939name;
        "i_1" = 367939;
        "i_2" = 367940;
        "i_3" = 367941;
        "i_4" = 367942;
        "i_5" = 367943;
        "image" = "<null>";
    }
)
```

I am very new to JSON parsing. I understand I can use something like:

```
for(NSArray *subArrayJSON in arrayJSON) {

}
```

to get each "object". But how do I get the data to populate my XCode objects.

Comment: Just alloc them up and and set properties as you normally do ... as you iterate over the json dictionaries

Comment: Take a look at [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: That chunk of "JSON" isn't really valid JSON. Not even close. Is that exactly how the data is coming back from your server?

Comment: No, that looks like an NSArray containing deserialised JSON, printed with NSLog.

Comment: What you have is an array of dictionaries -- deserialized JSON that has already been through NSJSONSerialization to deserialize it.

Comment: Before someone else jumps on you, they're not Xcode objects.  They are Objective-C objects.  Xcode is the IDE, Objective-C is the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you printed out the data that you received with NSLog. Actually not the while data, but the value for the "array" key.

NSLog prints arrays with ( parentheses ). And it prints dictionaries like { key: value; key: value; }. So the thing that you called arrayJSON is indeed an NSArray (you see the parentheses). And it contains dictionaries. And in these dictionaries you have keys "name", "i_1", "i_2" to "i_5" and "image". So to examine everything;

```
for (NSDictionary* dict in arrayJSON)
{
    NSLog (@"name = %@", dict [@"name"]);
    NSLog (@"i_1 = %@", dict [@"i_1"]);
}
```

and so on.

Comment: Of course, there's no need to actually do that, if all you want to do is NSLog the data, since just logging the array dumps everything.

Comment: On the other hand, usually people want to do more than just logging, and replace the NSLog statements with what they actually want.

Comment: Yep.  The trick is to be able to "read" the dump and understand what it means in terms of object structure.  Then writing the code is fairly simple.

Comment: This is what worked for me. Thanks!!!
    for (NSDictionary* dict in arrayJSON)
    {
        Pro *pro = [[Pro alloc]init];
        pro.Name = dict [@"name"];
        pro.interest1 = dict [@"i_1"];
        pro.interest2 = dict [@"i_2"];
        pro.interest3 = dict [@"i_3"];
        pro.interest4 = dict [@"i_4"];
        pro.interest5 = dict [@"i_5"];
        
        [self.pros addObject:pro];

    }